Using a Constructor in HQL gives MappingException when using it in repository interface but works fine when using it in service class
According to chapter Using a Constructor in HQL in https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-query-to-custom-class I should be able to use my DTO constructor in @Query select statement.
However when I try to do this I get MappingException. I would like to know what do wrong and how to fix this?
My error is:
2024-09-18 15:01:48.030 ERROR 15688 --- [nio-9997-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.example.cameldemo.dto.MyDto!] with root cause

org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.example.cameldemo.dto.MyDto!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext.getRequiredPersistentEntity(MappingContext.java:79) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.getRequiredPersistentEntity(PersistentEntities.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.wrap(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:90) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toModel(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:73) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.entitiesToResources(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:110) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.toCollectionModel(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:80) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.lambda$toModel$1(RepositorySearchController.java:204) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.toModel(RepositorySearchController.java:201) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(RepositorySearchController.java:185) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_402]

MyTable entitty class is:
package com.example.cameldemo.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class MyTable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;
    public String a;
    public String b;
    public String c;
}

My DTO class is:
package com.example.cameldemo.dto;

public class MyDto {

  public Long id;
  public String c;

  public MyDto(Long id, String c) {
    this.id = id;
    this.c = c;
  }
}

And my repository class is
package com.example.cameldemo.repository;

import com.example.cameldemo.dto.MyDto;
import com.example.cameldemo.entity.MyTable;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface MyTableRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyTable, Long> {

  @RestResource
  @Query("SELECT new com.example.cameldemo.dto.MyDto(mt.id, mt.c) FROM MyTable mt")
  List<MyDto> findAllWithQuery();

}

What do I need to do to be able to select DTO like that?
Edit: This question was closed as ClassNotFoundException, however I don't consider it to be an other ClassNotFoundException question. First of all ClassNotFoundException is never directly mentioned in stack trace and 2nd if I use that same class in any other way it does find the class. For example, if I create the following service method then it successfully returns me the List:
  public List<MyDto> findLimitedResults() {
    TypedQuery<MyDto> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT new com.example.cameldemo.dto.MyDto(mt.id, mt.c) FROM MyTable mt", MyDto.class);
    return query.getResultList();
  }

Edit [solution]: ✅ Turned out the problem with projection was that I was calling it directly over Spring rest interface. If repository returns projection or DTO then there needs to be something in between repository and rest response. For example rest controller that calls repository method and returns whatever repository method is returning. Or for better code style a service could be added in between rest controller and repository.
Here is working example:
Repository:
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface MyTableRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyTable, Long> {

  @RestResource
  @Query("SELECT new com.example.cameldemo.dto.MyDto(mt.id, mt.c) FROM MyTable mt")
  Object[] findAllWithQuery();

  @RestResource
  @Query("SELECT new com.example.cameldemo.dto.MyDto(mt.id, mt.c) FROM MyTable mt")
  List<MyDto> findAllWithQueryDto();

  @RestResource
  @Query("SELECT mt.id AS id, mt.c AS c FROM MyTable mt")
  List<MyProjection> findAllWithQueryProjection();

}

Controller:
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyTableRepository myTableRepository;

    @GetMapping("/myDtos2")
    public List<MyProjection> getMyDtos2() {
        return myTableRepository.findAllWithQueryProjection();
    }

    @GetMapping("/myDtos3")
    public List<MyDto> getMyDtos3() {
        return myTableRepository.findAllWithQueryDto();
    }

}


I think this is because it is treating MyDto as entity, so you have to use projection with interface.

According to baeldung it should work with just constructor like that also. But just in case I did try to create projection interface MyProjection with methods Long getId(); and String getC(); and then tried @Query("SELECT mt FROM MyTable mt") List<MyProjection> findAllWithQueryProjection(); but I got Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy147!

You have to define projection like this public interface MyProjection {     Long getId();     String getC(); } and try using query @Query("SELECT mt.id AS id, mt.c AS c FROM MyTable mt")

I tried that suggestion also. I got Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy159!.
